# Change selected value of <select> after it's created (via PHP) IF there's a value on the URL

Tags: php, css

I am creating a  like this:

```
<select name="id" id="id">
    <OPTION VALUE="null">Select<OPTION>
    <? foreach ($genres as $row){ ?>
        <OPTION VALUE="<? echo $row->id; ?>"><? echo utf8_encode($row->name); ?></OPTION>
    <?
       }
    ?>
</select>
```

I am using the $_GET to check for a value on the URL and then just take it and with that value I have to pre-select the option in the select menu, any ideas how to do this? I'm unsure of how to do it via javascript (or even if it would be more complicated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use

```
selected="selected"
```

on your pre-selected option

Comment: the thing is it's preselected by the user, so it has to be pre-chosen dynamically, you did give me an idea though =)

Comment: you just have to place if statement as you want. You did not tell us where should we check if user pre-selected it or not ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="id" id="id">
    <OPTION VALUE="null">Select<OPTION>
    <? foreach ($genres as $row){ ?>

        $selected = $_GET['your_var'] == $row->id ? 'selected="selected"' : false;

        <OPTION <? echo $selected; ?> VALUE="<? echo $row->id; ?>"><? echo utf8_encode($row->name); ?></OPTION>
    <?
       }
    ?>
</select>
```